# How tp send big Data set from loopback.js remote method

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I am reading oracle ref Cursor and storing in p_ref out param and using the streams from `resultset.toquerystream()` method I am reading the data and pushing the data in array variable and once reached end of the stream I am sending the data.

its working fine for small data set of 1000 records but failing with error ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE as you can see I am storing the data in array and returning the data once we reach end

but its failing with "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

```
oracledb.getConnection(
  ds.settings,
  function (err, connection) {
    if (err) {
      cb(err.message, []);
      return;
    }
    let count = 0;
    let params = {
      p_ref: {type: oracledb.CURSOR, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT}
    };

    let cursor = null;
    let queryStream = null;
    let data = [];
    connection.execute(
      sql,
      params,
      {outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT},
      function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          cb(err.message, []);
          doRelease(connection);
          return;
        }

        cursor = result.outBinds.p_ref;
        queryStream = cursor.toQueryStream();

        queryStream.on('data', function (row) {
          count++;
          data.push(row);
        });

        queryStream.on('error', function (err) {
          if (!cbCalled) {
            cbCalled = true;
            cb(err.message);
            doRelease(connection);
          }
        });
        queryStream.on('end', function () {
          console.log('Rows selected: ' + count);
          cb('', data);
          doRelease(connection);
        });
        queryStream.on('close', function () {
          if (!cbCalled) {
            console.log(count);

            doRelease(connection);
          }
        });
      }
    );
  }
);
```

Reference from here https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md

```
var stream = connection.queryStream('SELECT employees_name FROM employees');
stream.on('error', function (error) {   // handle any error... });
stream.on('data', function (data) {   // handle data row... });
stream.on('end', function () {   // release connection... });
stream.on('metadata', function (metadata) {   // access metadata of query });
```

Comment: Side note: the production node-oracledb documentation is https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the call to doRelease() from the 'end' event.